# How to add schedule elements into this calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, calendar

I'm hoping the lack of detail in this question won't result in it being labelled as badly formatted, but I've been playing around with this [codepen](http://codepen.io/centerlinescores/pen/EpFzd) css/js/jquery calendar/schedule script and I can't seem to find out how to add, say, reminders on specific dates. I have a database of things I need to do and the date by which they must be completed, I can access each date element (d/m/y) individually and was wondering how to actually implement my database into this calendar.

This is the html

```
<!-- HTML -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calendar</title>

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="//arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- SCRIPTS -->
        <script class="cssdesk" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script class="cssdesk" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script class="cssdesk" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script class="cssdesk" src="//arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.3/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Date</h1>

            <div id='calendar'></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And nowhere in the code does it indicate a div where I can add events, I hope some one can help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the calendar plugin documentation at http://fullcalendar.io

to include dates modify the javascript .. this snippet taken from the example on the homepage.

```
$(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2015-02-12',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [
        {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2015-02-01'
        },
        {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2015-02-07',
            end: '2015-02-10'
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2015-02-09T16:00:00'
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2015-02-16T16:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Conference',
            start: '2015-02-11',
            end: '2015-02-13'
        },
        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2015-02-12T10:30:00',
            end: '2015-02-12T12:30:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Lunch',
            start: '2015-02-12T12:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2015-02-12T14:30:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Happy Hour',
            start: '2015-02-12T17:30:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Dinner',
            start: '2015-02-12T20:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: '2015-02-13T07:00:00'
        },
        {
            title: 'Click for Google',
            url: 'http://google.com/',
            start: '2015-02-28'
        }
    ]
  });
});
```

Comment: what if I wanted to just add the information with php and html? Is there a quick way to do it?

Comment: modified answer with the js that you would include in the html page within a <script> tag. Generate the JSON data in PHP and the dates will appear in the calendar.